# Jquery hide function not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

This is my code where #my_tasks.php , #add_new_task.php , #add_new_lead.php , #follow_up.php are my ID selector (for li element)

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('<?php echo $v; ?>').hide();
            });
        </script>
```

where `$v=#my_tasks.php , #add_new_task.php , #add_new_lead.php , #follow_up.php` as string

It's not working (not hiding).please help me

Comment: And do you have elements matching that, with the class `.php` and the ID's etc ?

Comment: So is the li markup `<li id="my_tasks" class="php"></li>`?

Comment: Question would be:  what's actually being emitted to the browser, rather than what's in your PHP - for me, I'd start there and work way back to the PHP.

Comment: no it's not a class name, i used php file as id name @AndrewHewitt

Comment: No it's not a class name where <li id="my_task.php"></li> @emmanuel

Comment: Hi Lucin - my point is:  what's actually being sent back to your browser?  You'll need something like " $('#my_tasks.php , #add_new_task.php , #add_new_lead.php , #follow_up.php ').hide();".  If your PHP's not emitting that (or v.similar) it's not going to work.  HTH

Comment: i remove .php extension !! now it's working fine @AndrewHewitt

Comment: Of course - JQuery will interpret your ".php" file extension as a class selector!  Doh!

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('<?php echo str_replace(".","//.",$v); ?>').hide();
            });
</script>
```

You need to have escaping character before period (.).

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('<?= str_replace(".","//.",$v); ?>').hide();
            });
</script>
```